# cosigner took car

Tags: united-states, car

My son and his girl friend wanted to buy a car. My son was not working but he traded in his car and the car is in my name and the girl friend is a cosigner. Well, they broke up and she took off (we did not know she was going to) and took the car. It's my car too. What do I do about this? There is only one key  and she has it.

Comment: Does the girlfriend hold any legal or financial stake in the car? Did she sign any loan paperwork? Did she make any payments to either your son or the lender?

Answer (score 6):

Who is on the title?  If she is not on the title, and she has not responded to attempts to collect the car, file a police report that it's been stolen.

Comment: Well there is no title yet, we have made one payment.

Comment: @LauraLynnJauch the law requires that there is a title, but you cannot have it until you have paid it off.  The bank maintains it, except in a few states where the title and the liens are produced on separate documents.  The law does not care if someone owes money or not, it only cares who is on the title document.  If she were not a borrower, but on the title, it would be her car.  If she were on the loan, but not the title, then it is not her car.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to inform the lender ASAP. You are the primary lender and it will definitely affect your credit and hers if she stops the payments. You will definitely be contacted by the lender if there is a default in payment though. I will call the lender and inform them. They should be able to advise you on legality matters.